# What hosting method can be used for a WCF service to prevent multiple service start?

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

I'm developing a Client-Server Application which moderate Wireless Access Point.

I want change Server Application to a service with WCF. What hosting method can be used? **Service should run one time**.

I know i can host as windows service but It's to hard for me! If I use self-hosting with a Console Application (for example) ,this program ran 2 times,then two service will be hosted? (I know we can prevent an application from multiple running,but we should not prevent **application** from multiple running, we just prevent **service** from multiple hosting)

Comment: Do you mean a single **instance** running which will process service requests, or do you mean a single **invocation** of a service operation?

Comment: Please don't start your titles with "C# - ". That's what we have tags for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Self-hosting you can't have two applications on the same computer serve the same URL - so if your Console application with self-hosting is started twice and uses the same URL for WCF Server then the second start will throw an exception that the URL is already in use practically preventing your WCF Service from being served by two applications at the same time...